# Как правильно передать параметры для выражения WHERE id IN?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
var trs = '2,3,7';
var dicID = 3;

    var query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM directories_data WHERE id IN ($1::text) AND  id_directory=$2::int';

    var params = [
        trs, // $1 3,4
        dicID // $2
    ];

    dbClient.query(query, params);
```

При таком запросе пишет ошибку 
"Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов."
"оператор не существует: integer = text"

Comment: `id IN ($1::text)` действительно выглядит очень странно. У вас то ли `id` типа `text`, то ли вы проверяете включение на совершенно разных типах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить [официальной документации](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Parameterized-queries-and-Prepared-Statements#parameters-for-clause-where--in-), то проще всего будет использовать SQL конструкцию `ANY` вместе с аргументом-массивом:

```
var trs = [2, 3, 7];
var dicID = 3;

dbClient.query(
    'SELECT count(*) FROM directories_data WHERE id = ANY($1::int[]) AND id_directory=$2::int',
    [trs, dicID]
);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо работает!